# Overlapping bind-mounts and permissions in docker on linux

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions

Overlapping bind mounts on a linux host seems to create ghost files on the host machine owned by `root`. Is this intended? Here's an example:

```
# Create a file to mount in the container
touch hostfile
# Create a temporary directory to mount in the container
mkdir tempdir
# Run bash in the container and mount the file and directory
docker run --rm --volume=`pwd`/tempdir:/home --volume=`pwd`/hostfile:/home/hostfile ubuntu bash
```

After running the command, the `hostfile` can be found in the `tempdir` but is owned by `root`.

Note that

- running the same bash script on an OS X host results in the `hostfile` being owned by the user who started the container,
- specifying the user and group id of the user on the host machine as part of the `docker run` call does not change anything.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is the intended one. Let's try to understand what happens and perform the same mounts manually.

We create the `hostfile`, the "host" directory and the target "container" directory at some location (say, it is `/home/qazer/dockx` on my machine):

```sh
# the host file
$ touch hostfile

# the "host"-side dir
$ mkdir hostdir

# the "container"-side dir
$ mkdir contdir
```

Then we perform the mounts:

```sh
# the first mount: "host" dir to "container" dir
$ sudo mount --bind hostdir contdir

# success!

# the second mount: host file to the container file
$ sudo mount --bind hostfile contdir/hostfile
mount: contdir/hostfile: mount point does not exist.
```

Yay, the bind mount failed because the target file does not exist! Consulting the manpage for `mount(2)` system call reveals that this call would fail if some of the paths provided points to nonexistent file:

```
ENOENT A pathname was empty or had a nonexistent component.
```

So, what Docker actually does is the following:

```
$ sudo strace -f -p $(pidof containerd) \
              -e trace=%file,mount -yy |& grep -e hostfile -e home
...
[pid 23945] newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2c32423952d49f21e7a9c1addec6201c7f036c8dba1da975bac6a34d5abbe11/merged/home/hostfile", 0xc00016ce08, 0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
[pid 23945] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2c32423952d49f21e7a9c1addec6201c7f036c8dba1da975bac6a34d5abbe11/merged/home/hostfile", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0755) = 7</var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2c32423952d49f21e7a9c1addec6201c7f036c8dba1da975bac6a34d5abbe11/merged/home/hostfile>
[pid 23945] mount("/home/qazer/dockx/hostfile", "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b2c32423952d49f21e7a9c1addec6201c7f036c8dba1da975bac6a34d5abbe11/merged/home/hostfile", 0xc00013bb00, MS_BIND|MS_REC, NULL) = 0
```

First, the existence of the `/home/hostfile` file is checked in the container file system (the `newfstat()` call). This file is not present (`ENOENT`), so Docker **creates** it to avoid the error we've seen before (the `openat(O_CREAT)` call), and only after this the container engine performs the actual bind mount of `hostfile` to the container file system (the `mount()` call).

At the time of writing, the `/home` directory is already bind-mounted from the host (the first mount), so this write goes to this host directory. Finally, when the container stops, the file written by Docker stays in the host directory, and this is what you see.

As to the file ownership in case of Mac OS host — I think that the reason is the same as in [this your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890420/why-does-the-uid-of-files-created-in-a-docker-bind-mount-differ-based-on-the-hos).