# Why does the uid of files created in a docker bind mount differ based on the host OS?

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu

Running the following command creates a file `foo` in the current directory.

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/workspace -w /workspace alpine:3.10.2 touch foo
```

On my Mac (macOS 10.14.6 (18G95), Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc), the created file is owned by "me" as confirmed by the output `ls -l foo`.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 till  staff  0 11 Sep 14:08 foo
```

However, on a workstation (Ubuntu 16.04.1, Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc), the created file is owned by `root`.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 11 13:32 foo
```

Do you know why the same command produces different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Mac user, but I believe that I know what happens: what you see is *probably* the consequence of the fact that Docker for Mac actually runs Docker inside the virtual machine.

When you run Docker in Linux, which is the native environment for Docker, everything works as expected: the containerized process is the ordinary process running on the host kernel; it has some UID and GID (in your case — `0:0`, i.e. `root:root`), and when this process creates any file, this file is owned by these UID and GID. Docker volumes in Linux are just bind mounts, so nothing special happens here when the write propagates from the container to the host system.

When you do the same in Mac, things are more complicated: Docker does not run directly on the Mac host, instead, it uses a Linux virtual machine under the hood, which, in turn, runs Docker. In this case, volume is **not** just a bind mount — the work with directories mounted to the VM is governed by the hypervisor.

I'm not familiar with the specific hypervisor which is used by Docker in Mac, but, for example, in VirtualBox, when you share some host directory with the VM, the actual mountpoint inside the VM has a special filesystem type (`vboxsf`), and the driver for this filesystem is a part of VBox's guest additions, which assist the host-VM interaction.

The result of writes to this directory from within the VM is exactly what you observe: the owner is *translated* by VBox to the appropriate UID/GID.

Say, I have a directory `/test` inside a VM which is synced with the host:

```
# mount | grep test
test on /test type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

And I write something to this directory while being `root`:

```
# cd /test
# echo abcd > testfile
# ls -ln
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 5 Sep 11 14:57 testfile
```

As you see, the owner of this file is not `root` — it is translated to `1000:1000`. The same file from the host is:

```
$ ls -ln test
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 5 Sep 11 17:57 testfile
```

So, it's highly likely that you observe the same behavior: the hypervisor used by Docker (whatever it is in your system) performs the same translation when Docker in Linux VM performs a write to the volume, and you see the file with the altered owner (your `user:group` instead of `root:root`).